# Selenium: Why my get_cookies() method returned a list in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Below is my script:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://www.google.com")

all_cookies = driver.get_cookies()

print all_cookies
```

---

and the print result is:

```
>>> 
[{u'domain': u'.google.com.hk', u'name': u'PREF', u'value': u'ID=999c3b8cf82fb5bc:U=7d4d0968915e2147:FF=2:LD=zh-CN:NW=1:TM=1341066316:LM=1341066316:S=kDqT8587qbZJj1_B', u'expiry': 1404138316, u'path': u'/', u'secure': False}, {u'domain': u'.google.com.hk', u'name': u'NID', u'value': u'61=AbRSUZokdEP3hN79nLdNOWwlF7itUX9-pmFAIBb-ysJqvoi1NBsmOa2wV7ldWgXpYBd_OsPnMxaAPiRsJyCpVbCN882MWNn6DwNm9eD6PTKU2gfDfqrj2EJr6CNVUhI6', u'expiry': 1356877516, u'path': u'/', u'secure': False}]
>>>
```

The return is a list, but it should be a dictionary.

Comment: A dictionary would not be a proper storage for a cookie jar. There might be multiple cookies with the same name but different domains/paths.

Answer (score 22):

Cookies contain a lot more information than simply name and value information, for example expiration date, domain, etc. Therefore, a simple key/value pair is not sufficient. If all you're interested in ONLY the name and its corresponding value, then I'd do something similar to the following to construct your own dictionary:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
cookies_list = driver.get_cookies()
cookies_dict = {}
for cookie in cookies_list:
    cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']

print(cookies_dict)
```

Comment: Dictionary comprehension is perfect for this: `cookies = { c["name"]: c["value"] for c in driver.get_cookies() }`

Answer (score 6):

I understand that `get_cookies()` returns a **list of dictionaries**, each dict holding the properties for each cookie found:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#cookies

Answer (score 4):

since you asked for all cookies with `driver.get_cookies()` it returns a list of dictionaries with (key, value) pair for each cookie stored. If, instead you are interested in a specific cookie identified with a name `name` you can request for that specific cookie by name with `driver.get_cookie(name)` which Returns the cookie if found, None if not.

i.e.

```
driver.get_cookies() #returns list of cookie dictionaries
driver.get_cookie(name) # returns a cookie dictionary of specified cookie
```